# New BLOB losing data javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, blob, electron, web-mediarecorder

I am trying to save a BLOB like this

```
function stopRecording() {

recorder.stop();
console.log(blobs)

toArrayBuffer(new Blob(blobs, { type: "video/webm" }), function(ab) {
    console.log(ab)
    var buffer = toBuffer(ab);
    var file = `./SavedVideos/example.webm`;
    fs.writeFile(file, buffer, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Failed to save video ' + err);
        } else {
            console.log('Saved video: ' + file);
        }
    });
});
}


  function toArrayBuffer(blob, cb) {
console.log(blob);
let fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.onload = function() {
    let arrayBuffer = this.result;
    cb(arrayBuffer);
};
 fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
}

function toBuffer(ab) {
console.log(ab);
let buffer = new Buffer(ab.byteLength);
let arr = new Uint8Array(ab);
for (let i = 0; i < arr.byteLength; i++) {
    buffer[i] = arr[i];
}
return buffer;
}
```

When I print out the "chunks" blob, it has data, but when it is converted to Array Buffer, all the data is lost.

How can I fix this?

Comment: i am using node.js

Comment: Yeah im referring the blobs variable as chunks. I am using electron to run this.

Comment: And what happens if you try to play directly the generated Blob in a video element  (i.e before the `toArrayBuffer`: `var v=document.createElement('video'); v.src=URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(blobs,{type:'video/webm'}));v.play();`) What if you wrap your export code in the `recorder.onstop` event instead of doing it just after the call to `recorder.stop()`?

Comment: I get 416 (requested range not satisfiable error). The blobs are not empty though. When I print it to console there is data on it.

Comment: It still returns an empty file when I use recorder.onstop

Comment: This is how I am checking ->

console.log(blobs) 

This gives me a blob array with data.

I do this ->

var newblob = new Blob(blobs,{type:'video/webm'}); 

And when i print this out, its empty.

Comment: So the problem is not with the part you shown us, but above. Are you sure that all the Blobs in `blobs` Array have a `size` greater than 0? Where does the stream you record comes from? Can you also check for `recorder.stream.enabled`?

Comment: Size of blobs array is always 1. I get the stream using navigator.webkitGetUserMedia which uses Media Recorder

Comment: recorder.stream.enabled gives me false.

Comment: That's your problem. The stream you are trying to record is muted. You might be stopping it somewhere. Note that `navigator.webkitGetUserMedia` is deprecated, you should use the new [`navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) instead.

Comment: When i use navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia, i lose some functions like recorder.stop(), Why would my stream be muted? I am not stopping it anywhere and most tutorials use navigator.webkitGetUserMedia

Comment: Can you please check out my code on that page? https://codeshare.io/2Koe1E

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *'I lose some functions"*. It may throw an error, but disappear... This new API doesn't behave the same as the old gUM, now it returns a Promise, and constraints formats also have changed. So you'll need to modify a bunch of your code. I think [this article](https://medium.com/@chris_82106/implementing-webrtc-screen-sharing-in-a-web-app-late-2016-51c1a2642e4) is more up to date than many others about screen-sharing. Also, [electron's docs](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/desktop-capturer/) use the `mediaDevices` gUM, even though they don't use it correctly...